# Dos command xcopy to have current date - 90 days variable

Tags: dos, batch-file

i need to a .bat file to copy with xcopy command the files from a specific directory that are 90 days new. that means to take the todays date and take out 90 days of it and do not perform the copy.

help is needed,

thx

Comment: Does it have to be `xcopy`? Can't you use `forfiles`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROBOCOPY` not `XCOPY`. It will do what you want very easily. Robocopy is installed on Windows 7 and is a free download for other versions.

```
ROBOCOPY /S /MAXAGE:90 P:\path\to\source Q:\path\to\dest
```

There are many other options, for minimum age, min and max size, attrributes, filtering by file and directory names, and so forth.

Also you can use the /L option to just list what it would have done, to check you have the other options right.

Comment: Hello i have in place the following robocopy command: "robocopy.exe C:"\Documents and Settings\%username%\Desktop" \\192.1.1.10\%username%\Desktop *.* /e /xf \\192.168.1.1\nonbackupfiles.txt /MAXLAD:180 /FP /TS /LOG+:\\192.168.1.1\log\desktop\%username%.log - i just want to confirm with you guys that i copy only the newer files each time i call the command, and that i copy the files which are used the last 180 days. thx in advance.

Comment: No that will not work: Files on the desktop will ALWAYS show last-access date of the last time the user logged on or later, because the system accesses them to get their properties. You should use MAXAGE instead. Generally access date is useless on modern computers, as they access files too often for it to be a useful piece of information.

Comment: Hello. Thx for the answer. Then i will replace to MAXAGE and it will exclude i guess files which were modified before 180 days. Thx